# How to enable TLS in jedis while connecting with Redis cluster

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

We are using Redis for cache in application which is configured in spring beans, spring-data-redis 1.7.1, jedis 2.9.0.

How to enable TLS in jedis while connecting with Redis cluster ?

Please comment if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You ***might*** actually need a slightly version of spring-data-redis but with spring-data-redis version 1.8.11 and jedis 2.9 this works:

```
<beans:bean id='cacheManager'
        class='org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager'
        c:redis-operations-ref='redisTemplate'/>
<beans:bean id='redisTemplate' class='org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' p:connection-factory-ref='jedisConFac' />
<beans:bean id='jedisConFac' class='org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory' p:host-name='HOST' p:port='PORT' p:use-ssl='true' />
```